# Mongodump specify the output and filename

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodump

Is there a way to specify the whole path when running mongodump? I tried using --out but what it does at the moment is saving into a file at `my_given_path/database/collection_name.json.gz`

I have the following:

```
path = file_path + '/' + database + '/' + collection + '/'
query_input = "{\\\"metadata_id\\\": {\\\"\$oid\\\": \\\"" + metadata_id + "\\\"}}"
command = "mongodump --uri " + connection_string + database + " " \
          "--collection=" + collection + " --query=\"" + query_input + "\" --gzip --out=" + path + " --quiet"
```

for which the file is saved at:
`file_path/database/collection/database/collection.json.gz`

Ideally I would like to save it into
`file_path/database/collection/metadata_id.json.gz`

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--archive=<file>` flag instead of `--out`